# Row and column index data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Say we have the following data table:

```
> DT1
  11 12 13 14
  15 16 17 18
  19 20 21 22
  23 24 25 26
  27 28 29 30
  31 32 33 34
  ...
```

And this the new output:

```
> DT2
  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
  23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
  ...
```

I realized this with a data.frame and a for loop. How can I realise it with data.table? The dataset is much bigger and the for loop in the data.frame is a littlebit slow.

A little example of my loop:

```
for ...
  DT2[1,1:4]  <- DT1[1,]
  DT2[1,5:8]  <- DT1[2,]
  DT2[1,9:12] <- DT1[3,]
  DT2[2,1:4]  <- DT1[4,]
  ...
end for
```

Can I improve it with data.table's? How is the syntax for the loop?

Comment: Please clarify your question. data.table is a package which implements a specific data structure. Are you dealing with data.tables or data.frames? Also, in your "`for` loop" there is nor index variable.

Comment: As yet I handle it with data.frames. I try it with data.table to improve the loop but i dont know how the syntax is.
The for loop is only an example to demonstrate what i am doing without indexes.

Sorry for my bad englisch :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all entries in `dt1` are of the same type (either numbers or strings or `TRUE`/`FALSE`), then this will be easier and faster to do with reindexing/reshaping matrices:

```
dt1 <- matrix(11:34, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
dt1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   11   12   13   14
#[2,]   15   16   17   18
#[3,]   19   20   21   22
#[4,]   23   24   25   26
#[5,]   27   28   29   30
#[6,]   31   32   33   34
dt2 <- matrix(as.vector(t(dt1)), ncol=12, byrow=TRUE)
dt2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20    21    22
#[2,]   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31    32    33    34
```